# Date Formatter 24-Hour time with two digits

Tags: swift, dateformatter

I am trying to check if a string contains a 24-hour time.
Here is my current code:

```
func isMilTime(from string: String) -> Bool {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
    if (dateFormatter.date(from: string) != nil) {
        return true
    }else{
        return false
    }
}
print(isMilTime(from: "9:2")) //true
```

Currently single digit time like "9:2" is returning as true. How can I modify this to detect only two-digit time like "9:02"?

Comment: You want to allow `9:02`? `9` is only a single digit though?

Comment: you want to print(isMilTime(from: "9:2"))  printing false ?

Comment: @zeytin yes. Because if I remove the semicolon from the time like```dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HHmm"``` , print(isMilTime(from: "32")) is printing true. So to eliminate this I need it to return false.

Comment: @Sweeper I only need the minute part to have two digits.

Comment: @Ibrahim99 i could not understand why you need to remove the semicolon. 9:20 and 9.2 is same thing in terms of dateformatter. You really need to distinguish both of two then why don't you check the literally at the beginning.

Comment: Even without removing the colon, 9:2 seems an odd way to represent time. So is there a way to modify the date formatter to ignore strings like 9:2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check only the format I'd suggest a Regular Expression solution, it returns `true` for the range `0:00 – 23:59`

```
func isMilTime(from string: String) -> Bool {
    return string.range(of: "^(2[0-3]|[01]?\\d):[0-5]\\d$", options: .regularExpression) != nil
}

print(isMilTime(from: "9:2")) //false
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regex to check the format as @vadian suggested seems to work.

```
func isMilTime(from string: String) -> Bool {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
    if (dateFormatter.date(from: string) != nil) && isMilTimeReg(from: string) {
        return true
    }else{
        return false
    }
}

func isMilTimeReg(from string: String) -> Bool {
    return string.range(of: "^\\d{1,2}:\\d{2}$", options: .regularExpression) != nil
}

print(isMilTime(from: "2:3"))//false
```

Comment: Please see my edited answer. It avoids the `DateFormatter` check.